# How to pass a value from second view controller to first view controller through coordinator pattern

Tags: ios, swift, coordinator-pattern

I want to use Soroush Khanlou coordinator pattern (http://khanlou.com) in my iOS app. My problem is how can I pass data back to my first view controller through coordinators?
Before using the coordinator pattern, I used a delegate(protocol) to pass data back from second view controller to the first one, because my first view controller was responsible for creating and presenting the second view controller, that was not a good solution. So I decided to use coordinator
to remove the job of app navigation from my view controllers.
This is the scenario:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var coordinator: MainCoordinator?

    func showSecondViewController(data: Data) {
    coordinator?.presentSecondViewController(data: data) {[weak self] in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        //Do something
    }
}


class MainCoordinator: NSObject, Coordinator {

    var childCoordinators = [Coordinator]()
    var navigationController: UINavigationController

    init(navigationController: UINavigationController) {
        self.navigationController = navigationController
    }

    func start(completion: (() -> Void)?) {
        navigationController.delegate = self
        let firstViewController = FirstViewController.instantiate()
        firstViewController.coordinator = self
        navigationController.pushViewController(firstViewController, animated: false)
    }

    func presentSecondViewController(data: Data, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let child = SecondCoordinator(data: data, navigationController: navigationController)
        childCoordinators.append(child)
        child.parentCoordinator = self
        child.start() {
            completion()
        }
    }

    func refresh(data: SomeDataType) {
        //data from second view controller is here but I don't know how to pass it to my first view controller
        //there is no reference to my first view controller 
        //what is the best way to pass data back?
    }
}



class SecondCoordinator: Coordinator {

    weak var parentCoordinator: MainCoordinator?
    var childCoordinators = [Coordinator]()
    var navigationController: UINavigationController
    var data: Data!

    init(navigationController: UINavigationController) {
        self.navigationController = navigationController
    }

    convenience init(data: Data, navigationController: UINavigationController) {
        self.init(navigationController: navigationController)
        self.data = data
    }

    func start(completion: (() -> Void)?) {
        let vc = SecondViewController(data: data)
        vc.coordinator = self
        vc.delegate = self. //here I used delegate to get data from second view controller to pass it to first view controller
        navigationController.present(vc, animated: true) {
            completion!()
        }
    }
}

extension SecondCoordinator: SecondViewControllerDelegate {
    func refresh(data: SomeDataType) {
        parentCoordinator?.refresh(data: data) // I need to pass this data to my first view controller
    }
}
```

Comment: i guess you need the delegate pattern

Comment: use two closures one in second and another in coordinator to pass value to firstViewcontroller

Comment: @Sh_Khan Thanks for your reply. Are you saying I need to define a protocol in MainCoordinator and then implement it in my firstViewController?

Answer (score 0):

Using delegate pattern or closure callback pattern, you can pass a value from second view controller to first view controller.

If you use delegate pattern, data flow is below.
SecondViewController -> SecondViewControllerDelegate -> SecondCoordinator -> SecondCoordinatorDelegate -> FirstCoorfinator -> FirstViewController

If you use closure callback pattern, you will pass a closure as a parameter of 
start method or initializer of SecondCoordinator.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes I can add coordinator?.delegate = self in showSecondViewController method in my firstViewController, but I'm looking for the best solution and having two delegates, one from firstViewController to MainCoordinator and vice versa is not the best solution I think, I don't know maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @HastiRanjkesh how did you do it at last ?